# Quering `IntegrationEventLogs` on `eshopOnContainters` throws Execution Timeout Expired on SQL Server

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-core

When I have > 6000 IntergrationEnventLogs records in the database and I hit this [line](https://github.com/dotnet-architecture/eShopOnContainers/blob/4596d7aa99f841206e486e910d20b525cd48daf2/src/BuildingBlocks/EventBus/IntegrationEventLogEF/Services/IntegrationEventLogService.cs#L28):

```
var result = await _integrationEventLogContext.IntegrationEventLogs
            .Where(e => e.TransactionId == tid && e.State == EventStateEnum.NotPublished).ToListAsync();
```

as part of the normal execution.

I get the following error and stack trace:

```
Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Execution Timeout Expired.  The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding.
 ---> System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception (258): The wait operation timed out.
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.<>c.<ExecuteDbDataReaderAsync>b__208_0(Task`1 result)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.ContinuationResultTaskFromResultTask`2.InnerInvoke()
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
--- End of stack trace from previous location ---
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ExecuteWithThreadLocal(Task& currentTaskSlot, Thread threadPoolThread)
--- End of stack trace from previous location ---
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalCommand.ExecuteReaderAsync(RelationalCommandParameterObject parameterObject, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalCommand.ExecuteReaderAsync(RelationalCommandParameterObject parameterObject, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.SingleQueryingEnumerable`1.AsyncEnumerator.InitializeReaderAsync(AsyncEnumerator enumerator, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.Storage.Internal.SqlServerExecutionStrategy.ExecuteAsync[TState,TResult](TState state, Func`4 operation, Func`4 verifySucceeded, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.SingleQueryingEnumerable`1.AsyncEnumerator.MoveNextAsync()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.EntityFrameworkQueryableExtensions.ToListAsync[TSource](IQueryable`1 source, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.EntityFrameworkQueryableExtensions.ToListAsync[TSource](IQueryable`1 source, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at IFMS.GMT.BuildingBlocks.IntegrationEventLogEF.Services.IntegrationEventLogService.RetrieveEventLogsPendingToPublishAsync(Guid transactionId) in D:\repos\IntegratedFleetManagementSystem.GMT\src\BuildingBlocks\BuildingBlocks.IntegrationEventLogEF\Services\IntegrationEventLogService.cs:line 38
   at IFMS.GMT.Services.VehicleManagement.WebAPI.Application.IntegrationEvents.VehicleManagementIntegrationEventService.PublishEventsThroughEventBusAsync(Guid transactionId) in D:\repos\IntegratedFleetManagementSystem.GMT\src\Services\VehicleManagement\VehicleManagement.WebAPI\Application\IntegrationEvents\VehicleManagementIntegrationEventService.cs:line 38
   at IFMS.GMT.Services.VehicleManagement.WebAPI.Application.Behaviors.TransactionBehaviour`2.<>c__DisplayClass4_0.<<Handle>b__0>d.MoveNext() in D:\repos\IntegratedFleetManagementSystem.GMT\src\Services\VehicleManagement\VehicleManagement.WebAPI\Application\Behaviors\TransactionBehaviour.cs:line 61
--- End of stack trace from previous location ---
```

Is this query slow? (if so are there any recommendations on how to improve it) because I tried to create an Index for TransactionId but still no changes.

Or my machine together with SQL Server instance its running

Comment: Have you tried capture the query in SQL Server Profiler and then look at the execution plan?

Comment: That is a simple query, so unlikely to be a query cost issue.  Investigate blocking in SQL Server. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/sql/database-engine/performance/understand-resolve-blocking  Your app may have a lock that is preventing this query from running.